# Has anybody run Sonic Fire Pro 6 on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: 19.10

We are running Ubuntu 19.10. We need to be able to use Sonic Fire Pro 6 by Smart Sound. I have tried to Google it and I have not been able to find any solutions. We have used alternatives to some of are Windows programs and others are running on Wine. I have bot been able to figure this program out.

We are new to Linux and Ubuntu and still learning daily.

Comment: We have bought a large library of music for SmartSound and we want to use it. Sonic Fire has a way to seperate and mix up all of the sounds in each clip and is royality free. I am hoping that we can use it with Ubuntu.

Comment: Is a Windows VM Guest an acceptable solution? Or are you looking for Wine-based solutions? You might get more help if you edit your question to explain what you have already tried...and the exact result. Complete error output, in context, is very helpful.

Comment: I am sorry. We were not sure if wine would work or if we would need to run a vm. We searched Google to see if someone was using it with Wine or with VM. We were unable to find anything. We have come to the conclusion we are going to have to use a VM.